# Append new line character to Hyper Body struct

Tags: rust, hyper

I am trying to modify the response that gets returned back from the echo example when using hyper. Their code sample is [here](https://hyper.rs/guides/client/advanced/).

The only thing that is different in my code is that I am trying to append a new line character to the end of my collection

```
(&Method::POST, "/echo/uppercase") => {
  let newLine = "\n".as_bytes().to_vec();
  let m = req.into_body()
    .map_ok(|c| {
        c.iter()
        .map(|byte| byte.to_ascii_uppercase())
        .collect::<Vec<u8>>()
        .append(&mut newLine) <-- this line
    });

  *response.body_mut() = Body::wrap_stream(m);
},
```

The compiler is returning

```
*response.body_mut() = Body::wrap_stream(m);
                                         ^ the trait `std::convert::From<()>` is not implemented for `bytes::bytes::Bytes`
```

Does the append modify the type of the collection so that it is no longer considered a Future stream for the `wrap_stream` method?

Also is this the preferred way to append things to a `Body` struct in hyper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure passed to `map_ok()` returns `()`, not the `Vec<u8>` you are expecting.

This is because `Vec::append()`, which you use to append the newline, returns `()`, not the modified `Vec`.

Simple solution: modify the closure to return the `Vec<u8>`:

```rust
|c| {
    let mut v = c.iter()
        .map(|byte| byte.to_ascii_uppercase())
        .collect::<Vec<u8>>();
    v.append(&mut newline);
    v
}
```

Since a newline is a one-byte character, it might make more sense to just add it to the `Vec` directly:

```rust
v.push(b'\n');
```

This avoids the unnecessary allocation of the newline `Vec` for every request.